# Stored Procedure is setting variable to value from wrong row

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am writing a stored procedure to query a specific table. The behavior I am seeing is really weird though. First let me layout my table design and some sample queries, to make this easier to explain:

**Table Structure:**

[image]

**All Rows for specific Reservation ID (Only 1 Row)**

[image]

Notice the value for the **FieldName** column, this will be important below.

**Stored Procedure being called (and result):**

[image]

Basically, this stored procedure returns the specified price (Flight price, Hotel price, Flight markup, Hotel markup, etc, etc..) and for the specified currency. All values are inserted into the **Reservations_CurrencyPrices** table, so they're only calculated once ever and not again (for performance reasons).

When debugging, I can see a problem, but I do not understand WHY this is happening:

[image]

Notice the value of the **@Result** variable is in the Locals window. This SHOULD NOT be... it makes no sense, because at this point any value for **'TotalMarkupPrice'** record has not been inserted and indeed the value of the **@Result** variable is being set to the price from the **'TotalPrice'** record.. which you can see in one of the images above where it's the only row in the table. So it seems that even though I have specified the `WHERE [FieldName] = @FieldName` condition and the value of `@FieldName` is **'TotalMarkupPrice'**, it returns the value from the row for **'TotalPrice'** instead. This makes no sense. What am I missing here?

I ran that query manually to see what the result would be and it correctly returns NULL, as you can see below:

[image]

Why, oh why is **@Result** being set to the wrong value? The WHERE clause is not being honored when inside the sproc, it seems.

Comment: Please show the full stored proc usp_Dashboard_GetBookingPriceForCurrency?  The screen shot didn't show the bottom half after IF (@Result IS NULL) .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your screenshot your code is:

```
WHERE [FieldName] = FieldName
```

, not what you think:

```
WHERE [FieldName] = @FieldName
```

Effectively, you are not using the `@FieldName` parameter.

Same problem one line below:

```
AND [ToCurrency] = ToCurrency
```

---

Since it is easy to miss one `@` symbol, I prefer to name parameters like this:

```
@ParamFieldName
@ParamToCurrency
```

Comment: Very well spotted. After a long day, sometimes one just needs a fresh pair of eyes. Thank you, Vladimir.